# Tomcat logs web interface

Tags: monitoring, tomcat, logging, interface

I have several production machines running Java servlets on Tomcat infrastructure.

When I want to look at the logs, I have to remote access the machine with ssh, and manually grep the logs for errors.

Is there a recommended open-source, monitoring-oriented web interface to Tomcat logs?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at logstash. Its like Google for logs with loads of input and output adapters.